# Adjust horizontal position of the tag of an equation

Tags: positioning, amsmath, tags

Both `LaTeX` and `amsmath` put *tags* aligned at right margin (in `reqno` mode by default), or aligned at left margin (in `leqno` mode).

I'd like a document where is posible that *tags* are separated of the margin by a fixed distance to say something like `\tagmarginsep` whether i use `leqno` or `reqno` mode.

### Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=0.7\textwidth,showframe]{geometry} % only for ajusting width and show margins
\usepackage{amsmath}
%---------------------------------------
% Switch between `leqno` and `reqno` mode in the same document
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------
\newlength{\tagmarginsep} % Distance required
%\setlength{\tagmarginsep}{1cm} % For example
%---------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\vspace*{2ex}
\noindent This equation is in \texttt{reqno} mode (by default)
\begin{equation}
x=y
\end{equation}
and the next equation, number \eqref{eq2}, is in \texttt{leqno} mode.
\leqnomode
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
a=b
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This gets something like

[image]

However i'd like something like

[image]

where the length of the *red line*(obviously without to draw this line) must be the separation between *tag* and *margin* controlled by `\tagmarginsep`. Is this possible for all (or some) numbered (or tagged) equations?

Comment: and what you will do at long equation? here usually people ask how to fit equation in text width space :)

Comment: What should happen if the numbers gets larger, e.g. (10)?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, if the numbers are larger they must extend toward the center of the page as is done by default but keeping the separation of the margin fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change \displaywidth and/or \displayindent:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[width=0.7\textwidth,showframe]{geometry} % only for ajusting width and show margins
\usepackage{amsmath}

%---------------------------------------
% Switch between `leqno` and `reqno` mode in the same document
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}

\makeatother
%---------------------------------------
\newlength{\tagmarginsep} % Distance required
\setlength{\tagmarginsep}{1cm} % For example

%---------------------------------------
\begin{document}\makeatletter 

\everydisplay{\displayindent=\tagmarginsep \displaywidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tagmarginsep}
\vspace*{2ex}
\noindent This equation is in \texttt{reqno} mode (by default)
\begin{equation}
x=y
\end{equation}
and the next equation, number \eqref{eq2}, is in \texttt{leqno} mode.
\leqnomode
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
a=b
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `amsmath` this becomes possible by redefining `\tagform@`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\newdimen\tagmarginsep\tagmarginsep=10mm

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}
\def\tagform@#1{%
    \iftagsleft@\hspace{\tagmarginsep}\fi%
    \maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
    \iftagsleft@\else\hspace{\tagmarginsep}\fi}
%fixing eqref:
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup {\maketag@@@ {(\ignorespaces\ref {#1}\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    e=mc^2
    \label{eq1}
\end{equation}
see \eqref{eq1} for yourself
\leqnomode
\begin{equation}
    e=mc^2
    \label{eq2}
\end{equation}
see \eqref{eq2} for yourself
\end{document}
```

Comment: This won't work. It affects also references, add a label and try abc \eqref{test} xxx

Comment: This doesn't work leaving space at left when `leqno` option is loaded. Morever if i use a reference with `\eqref{<label>}` adds `\hspace{...}` at right of _equation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't use `\eqref` myself (literally never did), but you're right, it doesn't work with it.

Comment: @skpblack the skipping for the `leqno` option is easy done (see edit), but the problem with `\eqref` persists.

Comment: @skpblack fixed `\eqref` see edit.

Comment: @Skillmon i will do some tests before accepting this answer in case there are new things, thanks.

Comment: @Skillmon,: simply redefine `\eqref` as `\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{(\ref{#1})}}` (I didn't check whether there are any side-effects).

Comment: @Bernard the idea was to use the same definition it has by default. And because it is defined as `\textup {\tagform@ {\ref {#1}}}` by default I used the default definition of `\tagform@` for that (though I recognized that it is long by default).