# How to adjust the distance between the equation number and the right margin in amsmath?

Tags: amsmath, tags

I am using `pdfLaTeX`. If no packages are used, then, in displayed equations, the line numbers are flushed right. But if I want them to be a certain distance, say 0.35em, from the right margin, I can accomplish that by redefining `\@eqnnum` like this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@eqnnum{{\normalfont \normalcolor (\theequation)\hspace{0.35em}}}
\makeatother
```

However, if `amsmath` is used, then the above has no effect.

Suppose I am using `amsmath`. How can I insert an arbitrary but fixed distance between equation numbers and the right margin? The solution should insert the same distance for all displayed math environments (`equation`, `multline`, `align`, etc.).

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386084/adjust-horizontal-position-of-the-tag-of-an-equation)

Comment: @Denis Yes, that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't manipulate low-level TeX macros directly, as doing so could have unintended and unfortunate consequences. Instead, I'd pursue a high-level approach, e.g., by employing the `\newtagform` and `\usetagform` macros of the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools) package. One reason I think this is a wise thing to do is that it makes it very easy to switch back and forth among various equation tag forms.

To create cross-references to the equations in questions, I suggest you load the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package and employ its `\cref` and `\labelcref` macros, in lieu of the `\eqref` macro that's provided by the `amsmath` package. A big advantage of `\cref` and `\labelcref` is that they can take multiple arguments, not just one at a time.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{showframe}  % to indicate edges of text block

\usepackage{mathtools}  % for \newtagform and \usetagform macros
\newtagform{space}{(}{)\hspace{0.35em}}

\setlength\textwidth{3in} % just for this example

\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} % <-- for \cref macro
\begin{document}
\usetagform{space}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:A} 1+1=2 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:B} 2+2=4 \end{equation}
A cross-reference to \cref{eq:A,eq:B}.

\usetagform{default} % revert to default tag form
\begin{equation}\label{eq:C} 3+3=6 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This has an unfortunate side effect: there is extra space added after equation number when it is referred to in text. For example, `Equation~\eqref{EqnExample},` ends up looking like this: `Equation (31) ,` (note the extra space between `(` and `,`).

Comment: @linguisticturn - I've updated my answer to address your concern. Basically, I suggest you not use `\eqref`. Instead, I suggest you load the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package and employ its user-level macros `\cref`, `\Cref`, and `\labelcref`. For instance, you could replace `Equation~\eqref{EqnExample},` with `\Cref{EqnExample},`.

Answer (score 4):

It's really unfortunate that `amsmath` uses the same internal macro both for the equation number and `\eqref`, but you can recycle https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261647/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
% detach \eqref and \tag making
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\eqreftagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\let\eqreftagform@\tagform@

\def\tagform@#1{%
  \maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)\quad}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{equation}\label{test}
1=1
\end{equation}
X\dotfill X

Now we want \eqref{test} and that the space is right.

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\quad` you can use `\hspace` with whatever length you prefer.

[image]